# Reloading tableview with new data leads to array index out of range error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have been teaching myself swift and have run into a problem I cannot figure out.  I have a view controller that provides a tableview of items listed by events (array of custom class objects) and filtered by the current date.  The program works as expected until I try to change days (controlled by PrevButton and NextButton).  When another tableview is loaded, the program crashes with an array index out of range error.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? and how do I fix this?  The code for the view controller is as follows:

```
import UIKit

var finishedEvent = Event()

class EventSelectionView: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var EventLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items:[String] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        EventLabel.text = selectedDate

        items.removeAll()

        println(items.isEmpty)


        for var index = 0; index < EventArray.count; ++index {
            println("in the loop")
            println(EventArray[index].due)
            println(selectedDate)
            if EventArray[index].due.rangeOfString(selectedDate) != nil{
                items.append(EventArray[index].name)
                println(items[index])
            }

        }
        println("After loop")
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        var tempEvent = Event()

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        for var index = 0; index < EventArray.count; index++ {

            if (EventArray[index].name == self.items[indexPath.row]){

                tempEvent = EventArray[index];

            }
        }
        println(tempEvent.ODWM)
        if (tempEvent.ODWM == "DAILY"){

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else if (tempEvent.ODWM == "WEEKLY"){

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        } else if (tempEvent.ODWM == "MONTHLY"){

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        } else{

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {


    }

    @IBAction func FinishEventButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

        for var index = 0; index < EventArray.count; index++ {
            println(EventArray[index].name);
            println(currentCell.textLabel!.text);
            if (EventArray[index].name == currentCell.textLabel!.text){
                finishedEvent = EventArray[index];

            }
    }

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finishEventSegue", sender: nil?)

    }

    @IBAction func PrevButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var tempDate = myDate()

        for var index = 0; index < calLoop.calendar.count; ++index{

            if calLoop.calendar[index].date == selectedDate{
                tempDate = calLoop.calendar[index - 1]
            }
        }

        selectedDate = tempDate.date

    }

    @IBAction func NextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        var tempDate = myDate()

        for var index = 0; index < calLoop.calendar.count; ++index{

            if calLoop.calendar[index].date == selectedDate{
                tempDate = calLoop.calendar[index + 1]
            }
        }

        selectedDate = tempDate.date

    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: You should show which line gives the error, but my guess is that you don't prevent the user from selecting "next" beyond the size of `calLoop.calendar` or selecting "previous" less than index 0

Comment: The error is not in the previous or next calls.  The page actually reloads and the error happens the last time through the loop in the viewDidLoad() function.

Comment: On which line?  Also, variables should start with a lower case letter.  Clsss names have a capital. This won't cause your crash but it is a strong convention that makes code easier to read

Comment: I suggest you set a breakpoint in that line and single-step through to see what is going wrong. You could remove that whole loop and use the filter function on your array. Also, why do you put the event name in your items array?  You could simply store the event object and avoid the loop in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: for var index = 0; index < EventArray.count; ++index {
        println("in the loop")
        println(EventArray[index].due)
        println(selectedDate)
        if EventArray[index].due.rangeOfString(selectedDate) != nil{
            items.append(EventArray[index].name)
            println(items[index])
        } <br/>  I believe the error is occurring somewhere in this block, but only when it is loaded a second time with events that exist for the selectedDate

Comment: Learn how to get an exception backtrace.  When you know how, come back and edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, if `EventArray[index].due.rangeOfString(selectedDate)` returns `nil`, you don't append an item to the `items` array.  At that point, your `items` array has fewer members than `EventArray`.

The next time though the loop, `index` is `1` higher than the number of items in your `items` array, and thus you get an index out of range in the `println(items[index])`.

Change the `println` to:

```
println(items.last!)
```